# monitor simple process output

Tags: monitoring, tail, output

On my system I can check a job's status using `qstat`:

```
$ qstat 2048930
Job ID                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
------------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
2123456                    run.pbs          kilojoules                 0 Q bigq
```

How can I continuously monitor this output? What I mean is, I would like the output to constantly update so that I see the latest status without re-entering the command. Something like `qstat 2048930 | tail -f`

Comment: See if you have the 'watch' command

Comment: I have this command.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to use `watch`:

```
watch qstat 2048930
```

That will run the command every 2 seconds and continuously update the output. If you don't have `watch` and can't install it, you can use a simple loop:

```
while :; do qstat 2048930; sleep 2; done
```

You can stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: you could also throw in a 'clear' there, after the sleep command, if your terminal supports it.